# string::erase doesn't take iterators?

Tags: c++, string, iterator, erase

I have a problem using the string function `erase` with iterators.

The function below takes names of input files and `.ini` files and creates the path for an output file. The path is defined as

```
dir + in_file + def_name + ini_file + ".txt"
```

I am using `erase` to erase the extensions of the input file names.

```
void Output::vDefault(string in, string ini)
{
 //save names
 strIn=in;
 strIni=ini;

 //get working dir
 char mydirectory[MAX_PATH] = {""};
 GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,mydirectory);

 //erase extensions
 strIn.erase(strIn.find_last_of('.'), strIn.end()); // error
 strIni.erase(strIni.find_last_of('.'), strIni.end()); // error

 //adr starts with folder
 strAdr=mydirectory;
 //and ends with name
 //address=dir+in_file+def_name+ini_file+.txt;
 strAdr+=strIn+DEFOUTNAME+strIni+".txt";    
}
```

Running the code causes the error below:

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::erase(unsigned int,unsigned int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'unsigned int'
```

`erase` can take two iterators as first and last. Can you help me? I don't know why it does not accept anything but `int` in my project.

Comment: Aside: You don't need to "save names", you're passing in the `string`s *by value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string::find_last_of()` doesn't return an iterator, so it can't match the iterator overload of `string::erase()`.

Fortunately, the `string::erase()` overload that takes an index for the position defaults to erasing from there to the end, so the following should work for you:

```
strIn.erase(strIn.find_last_of('.'));
strIni.erase(strIni.find_last_of('.'));
```

Of course, the string had better actually have a `'.'` character in it...

Comment: i check the '.' before. i will use strIn.erase(strIn.find_last_of('.')); thx

Comment: If the charactor is not found, you get `string::npos` back, which is the integral equivalent to `end()`, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the erase signature takes 2 size_t or 2 iterators. Not a combination.
find_last_of returns a size_t

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

```
string& erase ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos );
iterator erase ( iterator position );
iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

```
size_t find_last_of ( const string& str, size_t pos = npos ) const;
size_t find_last_of ( const char* s, size_t pos, size_t n ) const;
size_t find_last_of ( const char* s, size_t pos = npos ) const;
size_t find_last_of ( char c, size_t pos = npos ) const;
```

The solution is to use

```
string& erase ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos );
```

Here is size_t n optional.

> Erases a sequence of n characters starting at position pos. Notice
>   that both parameters are optional: with only one argument, the
>   function deletes everything from position pos forwards, and with no
>   arguments, the function deletes the entire string, like member clear.

```
strIn.erase(strIn.find_last_of('.'));
strIni.erase(strIni.find_last_of('.'));
```

Comment: it works if i use it like this: size_t tmp=strIni.find_last_of('.');
 strIni.erase(tmp, string::npos);   thx

Comment: You can ommit 'string::npos' and just do 'strIn.erase(strIn.find_last_of('.'));'

Answer (score 0):

[std::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) returns a `size_t` and not an iterator.